# Please explain example in nextTick documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

**Update**: This turned out to be a really stupid question. I just failed to notice some simple things in the quoted example.

I've been looking at information about ticks and the event loop, and mostly it's clear, but there is an example in [the nextTick documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) that puzzles me. It says:

> It is very important for APIs to be either 100% synchronous or 100%
>   asynchronous. Consider this example:
>
> ```
> // WARNING!  DO NOT USE!  BAD UNSAFE HAZARD!
> function maybeSync(arg, cb) {
>   if (arg) {
>     cb();
>     return;
>   }
>
>   fs.stat('file', cb);
> }
> ```
>
> This API is hazardous. If you do this:
>
> ```
> maybeSync(true, function() {
>   foo();
> });
> bar();
> ```
>
> then it's not clear whether foo() or bar() will be called first.

First questions: **why** is foo not guaranteed to be called first? There is a simple function call (of maybeSync), an *if*, and a callback of cb=foo. I take it that something in this chain is in some way (possibly) asynchronous, pushing something to the event queue and continuing execution? I don't see how anything there could have that effect.

Second question: is there some documentation somewhere that could have helped me understand this on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. `foo` is guaranteed to be called first if there's no `arg` as well as `foo` is guaranteed to be called "last" if there is an `arg`. Just imagine call stacks here:

**`arg` exists**

- maybeSync calls `cb` immediately within same event loop iteration. `foo` is called synchronously as well within same event-loop iteration
- maybeSync returns - so `fs.stat` is never called in this case
- `bar` is called after `foo` is done

**`arg` does not exist**

- maybeSync calls `fs.stat` (which is asynchronous) providing `cb` as a callback
- there's no more synchronous code to run within current event-loop iteration thus `bar` is called
- `fs.stat` is complete and it calls `cb` on the **next** event loop iteration (after `bar`). `foo` executes synchronously, but within another event loop iteration this time

Both are quite obvious. The problem here is that in most cases you don't know in advance if there's any `arg` value (otherwise there's no need in `if` :)) so you could have two scenarios of running this code which makes things pretty complicated.

`process.nextTick` mimics async nature of `fs.stat` here, so that `foo` is **always** called on the next event loop iteration making the flow predictable.

Comment: Hm, I'm confused about several things in this answer:
1. You inverted "foo does not exist" / "foo exists"? It cannot be called if it does not exist, can it?
2. Why would fs.stat only be called in one of the cases?
3. You seem to be saying that foo is always called before bar, if foo is called at all. So then I don't see what is not clear about the code, i.e., what is the point with the example.

Comment: 1. Woops, sorry - i meant `arg` here.  2. There's `return` statement so `fs.stat` will not be called if you do provide an `arg`. 3. `foo` is **always** called because `cb` is always called. The difference between these two examples is just the order of calls of `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Ah, ok so it's just a double case of temporary-code-blindness on my part: somehow I noticed neither the return statement (ugly! should have been an if-else in my opinion) nor the "cb" parameter to fs.stat. Thanks.